# Why the following sum converges? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{3}{2n}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1 - \frac{3}{2n}\right)^{n^2}$$

Isn't it divergent by the test for divergence? Because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{3}{2n}\right)^{n^2}=1$?

But according to the answer key it is convergent. How do you know this? What test do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Your result is false, since: $$\sf\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[1-\dfrac3{2n}\right]^{\displaystyle n^2}=0\neq 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Broad hint: let $x=\frac{2n}{3}$.  Then $n=\frac{3x}{2}$ and so $n^2=\frac{9x^2}{4}$, and the limit is $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\frac1x)^{9x^2/4}$ $=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left((1-\frac1x)^x\right)^{9x/4}$.  Now, the inner expression should look at least somewhat familiar to you; if you know your calculus, you can use it to bound the overall size of each term, and then use the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Your limit is wrong. Example, $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{-1}\neq 1$